# How important is the time it takes to graduate?

Tags: masters

In some countries (e.g. Greece) there is no penalty if you fail a course. You can simply try again next time. Also, there is no limit to the amount of time it takes to get a degree.

I am a good student who works hard and tries his best to get good grades.

Unfortunately, on my 1st semester some very bad things happened and I passed no courses for 3 semesters. I will explain this in my essay.

Is it reasonable for me to expect to be accepted by top US/UK universities for a Masters in Computer Science given that I get high grades, but I take 5-6 years instead of 4 to get my degree?

Comment: In [an answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10452/prolonging-undergraduate-school-to-do-research/10456#10456) to [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10452/prolonging-undergraduate-school-to-do-research), user JeffE states: "Nobody cares how long you took to graduate. There is no advantage to graduating early, and there is no disadvantage to graduating late."

Comment: As a fellow Greek (who finished his undergraduate many years ago), I know that the average time for finishing a 4-year degree is 5 years for those who actually start from the beginning. Passing no course for 3 semesters, means you already need 6-7 years to graduate.... (continued)

Comment: ....This "Is it reasonable for me to expect to be accepted by top US/UK universities" should be first replaced with "Will I be able to actually get the degree?" and then "Will I be able to actually get the degree with at least a 7.5/10?", since this average (or better) is a cutoff point not just for the best schools in USA (several question here state that a GPA 3/4 in the USA is the bare minimum) but any school.

Comment: @Alexandros: I see your points. Fact is, if I decide to do something I try my very best to do it, unless things out of my control happen. I am also aware of the average time to finish, but keep in mind those students are living a "more relaxed" student life. I am planning to work hard to finish in 5-6 years.

Comment: @MadJack Is that analogy fair? JeffE later states 'It is extremely common for students to take more than four years to get an undergraduate degree, especially if they change majors, as you are effectively doing.

' --> I'm assuming that that is relevant to JeffE saying 'no'.

Comment: @BCLC Well, I linked to both JeffE's answer and the question, so I guess it is up to the reader to draw their own conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

to answer your first question and then comment on a statement:

Personally I graduated from both High School, and my first B.S early. There's not advantage or disadvantage when another school (or even the school you attend) looks at your record to decide if you can enter the program. There isn't a disadvantage to graduating late either. The rate of students who graduate (In the U.S) has dropped the past years for a few reasons:

1). Financial issues.

2). Work & school at the same time limits the amount of courses you can take at one time.

3). Single-course to graduate students (there's no formal name for this so I'll explain). Some students take 1-2 courses a semester and may even skip a semester or two. They do this to keep educating themselves and eventually earn a degree without having to stress over taking 4-6 courses at once.

You mentioned failing courses because of personal reasons. Normally when this happen's grades are seen to drop and the student either drops out or get's back in the school motion and grades rise. You mentioned failing courses for 3 semesters which could look bad (granted I don't know what caused the issue in the first place). Be ready to talk about it in person and in your essay because it's unusually for someone who is failing semesters to continue to attend.